# WinAPI: simulate a full key press (key down and up)

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, keypress

I'm trying to simulate a key down and up event on a given window and I'm using `Spy++` to compare results.

```
public static void Keyboard(IntPtr windowHandle, Keys key)
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;

    var keyCode = (uint) key.GetHashCode();
    var scanCode = MapVirtualKey(keyCode, 0);
    var lParamDown = GetLongParam(0u, scanCode, 0u, 0u, 0u, 0u);

    try
    {
        PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(keyCode), new IntPtr(lParamDown));

        Thread.Sleep(50);

        var lParamUp = GetLongParam(0u, scanCode, 0u, 0u, 1u, 1u);

        PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_KEYUP, new IntPtr(keyCode), new IntPtr(lParamUp));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message); // Arithmetic overflow
    }
}

private static uint GetLongParam(uint repeatCount, uint scanCode, uint extended, uint contextCode, uint previousState, uint transitionState)
{
    return (transitionState << 31) | (previousState << 30) | (contextCode << 29) | (extended << 24) | (scanCode << 16) | repeatCount;
}
```

Apparently, the keydown event works just fine, however the key up part throws an Arithmetic exception. According to the MSDN, these are the flags mapping: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#keystroke-message-flags

Whats wrong in the above code and how do we successfully achieve this?

Note: Both C# and C++ were chosen for this post's flags as answers can be any of them.

Comment: So what line is your arithmetic overflow happening at?

Comment: Not an answer, but see [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: _"Note: Both C# and C++ were chosen for this post's flags as answers can be any of them."_ Sorry, Stack Overflow tags don't work this way, but broaden forcus of your question (that far it's going uto be close worthy). So I hope you don't mind I removed the [tag:c++] tag here. If any would have been appropriate, then it's [tag:c++-cli].

Comment: @πάν This is a native API. Following your reasoning, neither C# nor C++/CLI apply in that case, making this ultimately a C question. It also questionable which rule applies that would make an (in your opinion) mistagged question subject to closure. Mind to explain?

Comment: Either use `UIntPtr`, or change all your `uint`s to `int`. `new IntPtr(1u << 31)` is an overflow

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

```
private static int GetLongParam(uint repeatCount, uint scanCode, uint extended, uint contextCode, uint previousState, uint transitionState)
{
    return (int) (transitionState << 31) | (previousState << 30) | (contextCode << 29) | (extended << 24) | (scanCode << 16) | repeatCount;
}
```

Changing the return to `int` prevents the arithimetic overflow.

I also found that it's good to wrap the `new IntPtr(lParamUp)` in an `unchecked` statement, but so far that wasn't necessary as it's working without it, eg: `unchecked(new IntPtr(lParamUp))`.